# How to find resistor values for the Voltage range

Tags: voltage-divider

[image]

Here is the circuit. What is the formula to solve for R1 if given Vcc=5v, R2=50k, and I want the output range from 1-4v?

Comment: I'm assuming you want to find R3 also?

Comment: Your missing R3 (without it nothing can be solved). Also it would be a system of two equations not just one equation. Finally this sounds a lot like a homework problem. How would you start doing it?

Comment: What input impedance will the measuring device at Vout happen to have? Unless it is infinite it will need to be known to calculate the resistor values.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you assume no current flows out of the output then Ohms law gives you.
$$I = V_{CC}/(R_{1} + R_{2} + R_{3})$$
and also
$$V_{out}=R_{3}*I$$
which means that 
$$V_{out} = 5*R_{3}/(R_{1} + R_{2} + R_{3})$$

Solve for Vout = 1V when R2 = 50k and Vout = 4V when R2 = 0, everything beyond this point is basic maths.

From R2 = 0 we get...
$$4 = 5*R_{3}/(R_{1} + R_{3})$$
$$4*R_{1}+4*R_{3} = 5*R_{3}$$
$$R_{3} = 4*R_{1}$$

Plugging that into R2 = 50 we get
$$1 = 5*R_{3}/(R_{1} + R_{3} + 50)$$
$$R_{1} + 4*R_{1} + 50 = 20*R_{1}$$
$$15R_{1} = 50$$
$$R_{1} = 3.33k$$
$$R_{3} = 13.33k$$

If you re-arrange the equations above you can end up with a single equation for R1. This is a horrible way to do it but possible:

$$R_{1} = \frac{R_{2}*V_{Min}}{\frac{V_{CC}*V_{Max}}{V_{CC}-V_{Max}} - V_{Min}*(1 + \frac{V_{Max}}{V_{CC}-V_{Max}})}$$

$$R_{3} = \frac{R1*V_{Max}}{V_{CC}-V_{Max}}$$

Where Vcc is the supply voltage, Vmin is the minimum required output, Vmax is the maximum required output, and R2 is the maximum value of R2. It is assumed that the minimum value for R2 is 0. All vaules are in kOhms.

Putting those number in we get:
$$R_{1} = \frac{50*1}{\frac{5*4}{5-4} - 1*(1 + \frac{4}{5-4})}$$
$$R_{1} = \frac{50}{20 - (1+4)}$$
$$R_{1} = 3.33$$
$$R_{3} = \frac{3.33*4}{5-4}$$
$$R_{3} = 13.33$$

Comment: So where is the answer to my question asking about the formula to solve for R1?

Comment: You get R1 by solving the equations...

Comment: I've added the maths but this isn't exactly advanced stuff, you should have been able to do that yourself.

Comment: Even use an equation solver, I can't figure out the formula to solve R1. Getting the answer is not my question here. I only need to get the formula to solve R1: https://www.symbolab.com/solver/equation-calculator/5%3D4%5Cleft(b%2F%5Cleft(a%2Bb%5Cright)%5Cright)%2C%205%3D1%5Cleft(b%2F%5Cleft(a%2Bb%2B50000%5Cright)%5Cright)

Comment: That is just a case of re-arranging the lines above. I've added the end result.

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you choose the potentiometer end-to-end resistance value then choose R1 and R3 to each drop 1 volt. Then your wiper will extend from 1 volt up to 4 volts.

So if you choose the pot to be (say) 6 kohm then R1 = R3 = 2 kohm.

Or, if the pot is 10 kohm then R1 = R3 = 3.333 kohm: -

[image]

The advantage of this is that pots are usually more stable ratiometrically with temperature rather than as a rheostat. Another possible advantage is that the current drawn from the 5 volt rail is constant and the wiper resistance is not brought into play hence no error terms produced by it (assuming it connects to a high impedance circuit).

Comment: I am writing a calculator for this problem. to me a formula to solve r1 is all that I needed. While I know How to solve this problem by hand slower, I am not very good at math, so I can't figure out the formula.

Comment: Agreed. This is the answer I just came back to post.

Comment: @Atmega328 I appreciate that you are trying to solve formulas for a different circuit but, that circuit you propose is not as good as the one I propose for the good engineering reasons I gave. Best practice when there are no cost implications is a no-brainer.

Comment: @Atmega328 This is the more sensible option, and I have a spreadsheet based calculator for this very example if you go this route for your own. Labeling the resistors 1,2,3 from top to bottom, the formulas (translated from my spreadsheet) would be (R3/(R1+R2+R3))*Vin for your low output, and ((R2+R3)/(R1+R2+R3))*Vin for your high output.

Comment: @Andy aka I appreciate that you have ignored my question, created your own, and then answered your own question. I understand in the pov of a good engineer, my circuit is not as good as yours, and is probably harder to solve, but that is not really the answer to my question. and I am pretty sure my inferior circuit has some value in some situation, especially when used with a pot/slider resistor that doesn't have center tap.

Comment: @Atmega328 you are somewhat correct - I have tried to show you a better and more preferred circuit that is more useful and beneficial in the larger majority of situations.

Comment: +1 for excellent answer **actually useful for future readers**, and for keeping cool in spite of a clearly abusive behaviour from the OP.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach:

The voltage across the pot is :

$$V_{POT} = 4V - 1V = 3V$$ 
and the POT current is
$$ I_{POT} = \frac{3V}{50k\Omega} = 60\mu A $$

And now using Ohm's law we can find

$$R_1 = \frac{5V - 4V}{60\mu A} = 16.67k\Omega = 16k\Omega$$

And R3

$$R_3 = \frac{ 1V}{60\mu A} = 16.67k\Omega = 16k\Omega$$

But you need to change your circuit slightly

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxcbG1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: You can use this equations
$$R_3 = R_2*\frac{ V_{max} V_{min} }{V_{CC}(V_{max}-V_{min})} = 50 *\frac{4*1}{5*(4-1)} = 50*\frac{4}{15} = 13.33$$ 
and this one:
$$R_1 = R_3*\left (\frac{V_{CC}}{V_{max}}-1 \right)=13.33* \left (\frac{5}{4}  -1\right )= 13.33*\frac{1}{4} = 3.33 $$

Comment: Or $$R_1 = R_2*\frac{V_{min}(V_{cc} - V_{max})}{V_{cc} (V_{max} - V_{min})} = 50 \frac{(5-4)1}{5(4-1)} = 50\frac{1}{15} = 3.33 $$